# Implement Logout message in built-in back button and logout button

Tags: android

This is my MainMenu.java

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity{

    Button userinfo,requestservice,makepayment,trackparcel,checkcard, logout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        userinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
        requestservice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestservice);
        makepayment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makepayment);
        trackparcel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trackparcel);
        checkcard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkcard);
        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

        userinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, UserInfo.class);              
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        requestservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, RequestService.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        makepayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Payment.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        trackparcel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, TrackParcel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        checkcard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, CheckCard.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Login.class);
                SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                edit.clear();
                edit.putString("email", "");
                edit.putString("password", "");
                edit.commit();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void dispachBackKey() {
        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I want to trigger the built-in back button and I eventually found this code

```
public void dispachBackKey() {
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
}
```

You may notice that I have logout button as well, What I want to do is that how to display a small message to ask user of the confirmation of logout for **logout button** and **built-in back button**. How should I implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the back button, you could also use `public void onBackPressed()`. Then, you would just display a `AlertDialog` after each button press. Here's what that code would look like:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Logout")
    .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // logout
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // user doesn't want to logout
        }
     })
     .show();
```

This would be placed in the `onClickListener` for the Logout button, and also the `onBackPressed()` or however you want to detect a back button click. Here's an example of `onBackPressed()`:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //put the AlertDialog code here
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works well in my applications, thanks for the source code and get to learn how to trigger the back button as well thanks again ya~

Answer (score 0):

Use `onBackPressed()` to know when user is clicking back button,then show dialog for the confirmation of logout, and logout on click of `ok button` :

**Alert dialog Code:**

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Logout From Appname")
    .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // add your logout code here
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // dismiss dialog here because user doesn't want to logout
        }
     })
     .show();
```

Then show this Dailog on back button:

**onBack Pressed:**

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //use the AlertDialog code here for user confirmation
}
```

I this help you!

Comment: Although it success bring my user to my Login activity, but afterwards i found that once I reach Login activity and when I tap button should be go away from the application. But it does not go away but go back to MainMenu.class its quite troublesome now!!